# Xcode 14.3.1 - 'No Such Module Found' Error and App Blankness when Running in Rosetta Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, macos-ventura, rosetta

When I run my app in Xcode Version 14.3.1, it shows a "no such module iOSDropDown" error. I tried many solutions to clear this issue, but nothing worked well. So, I changed my running destination to the Rosetta simulator, and at that time, the app worked perfectly. However, sometimes the app became blank, and I don't know how to fix this issue. Is running the app in Rosetta simulator the right way to resolve the problem? Please help me.

My macOS version is Ventura 13.4.1, and the project was created in Xcode 9.3.

Updated Podfile and Build Settings, but Still Facing 'No Such Module Found'

Comment: First, Xcode does not support Rosetta anymore since version 14.3 (see [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes)). Second, please provide more details. Which module does Xcode complain about?